# Unable to Launch Activity Due to Incorrect Package Name

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I am building a project using maven and seem to be having some problems. When I launch the app I get the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.appname/com.appname.HelloAndroidActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.appname.HelloAndroidActivity
```

The first thing that looks wrong is this part

> com.appname/com.appname.HelloAndroidActivity

It looks like it is putting the package name in twice. To give a bit of background I used the quickstart from [here](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes) to build the project initially.

I also found [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81559) link that could be related but I am not sure if it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.appname" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

I have noticed this in my POM

> your.company

What is this normally set to?

Comment: there is my manifest. It looks ok to me

Comment: Uninstall the app, clean your project, build the project than run again

Comment: @Rocky thats strange. I actually have 2 projects with the same error. One worked after I rebuilt the other didn't

Comment: if you have both projects with same package name than you may get this kind of error

Comment: no they are different. Actually I would like one to be a library and the other to use that library. I am trying to get my head around how to use a apklib. I need to do more reading but cannot find good resources